# Change the resolution of the friction surface raster and compute cumulative travel time in R

Tags: raster, r, distance, resolution, least-cost

I have downloaded the 2015 friction surface from the [Malaria Atlas project website](https://malariaatlas.org/research-project/accessibility-to-cities/) (see bottom of the page). On their websites, authors specify that the measure units of such a raster are **minutes to cross one meter**. Then, following an [online guide](https://medium.com/@abertozz/mapping-travel-times-with-malariaatlas-and-friction-surfaces-f4960f584f08) and the help of the **gdistance**'s `accCost()` function, I made some tests to generate a travel time raster. Please check my reproducible example regarding travel time from Naples to Milan (two cities in Italy):

```
library(gdistance)
library(malariaAtlas)
library(raster)

# 1. Define latitude and longitude matrix for Naples and Milan
coords_naples <- as.matrix(data.frame("lon" = 14.26812,
                                      "lat" = 40.8518))
coords_milan <- as.matrix(data.frame("lon" = 9.189982,
                                     "lat" = 45.4642))

# 2. Import Italy's shapefile
italy <- getData(country = "ITA",
                 level = 0,
                 path = tempdir())

# 3. Import friction raster surface for Italy
fs_italy <- malariaAtlas::getRaster(surface = "A global friction surface enumerating land-based travel speed for a nominal year 2015",
                                    shp = italy)

# 4. Calculate (and geocorrect) the transition surface, according to the help of the accCost() function
transition_surface <- transition(x = fs_italy,
                                 transitionFunction = function(x) {1/mean(x)},
                                 directions = 8)
transition_surface <- geoCorrection(x = transition_surface)

# 5. Compute the cumulative cost surface (in minutes) to travel from Naples to everywhere in Italy
tt <- accCost(x = transition_surface,
              fromCoords = coords_naples)

# 6. Plot everything, to visually check the travel time
plot(tt)
plot(SpatialPoints(coords = coords_naples,
                            proj4string = crs(italy)),
                            cex = 2,
                            pch = 19,
                            add = TRUE)
plot(SpatialPoints(coords = coords_milan,
                            proj4string = crs(italy)),
                            cex = 2,
                            pch = 19,
                            add = TRUE)
```

This example works correctly. On the last plot generated, it can be seen that the cumulative travel time from Naples to Milan is a bit less than 500 minutes, which correspond to almost 8 hours, and this is reasonable (you can check this on Google Maps). I've made the same tests also for smaller distances, and they all return reasonable travel times.

**THE PROBLEM**
The friction surface raster has a resolution of ~1 km² (0.00833333°*0.00833333°). However, I am mostly working with rasters of ~10 km², but if I aggregate the pixels of the friction raster with a factor of 10, all the subsequent steps do not make sense anymore to me, because the resulting travel time doesn't match with my expectations. You can add the following code after point # 3. and check it yourself:

```
fs_italy <- aggregate(x = fs_italy,
                      fact = 10,
                      fun = mean)
```

I don't understand which are the measure units in the final raster, and if I should correct them before or after computing it. In addition, I am also not sure about the correct aggregation method I should use in this situation.